# Thunderbird freezes when downloading large mails

Tags: 10.04, thunderbird

I have three mails boxes. While downloading mails with large attachments, thunderbirds freeze (going gray). anything is fine when downloading is finished but by the way i can't read my mails in this time.

Has someone had this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going gray does not nessesarily mean that TB crashed with a freeze. It signals you that the application is busy. Only being busy for an endless time would be a freeze. If your application continues running after the download finished IMO everything is just fine.

Failure to read already downloaded mails while a larger download runs is more like a wishlist feature for TB. But consider this: when having set up your account with IMAP you may not be able to add a further download when the program still is busy downloading.